# APACHE/PHP error log

Tags: php, apache-2.2

I run website on APACHE and PHP on Debian. Sometimes I see the following error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

My question is, where do I find this log? Is it configurable?

Thank you

Comment: What OS? What distribution?

Comment: Look in your `httpd.conf` and `php.ini` for the configuration directives specifying the location of the error log. `/var/log/httpd/error_log` is a common location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

probably

You can config it in

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

In case you use Debian

Comment: "In case you use Linux"... this is not the default location or name of the Apache configuration file or error log in many Linux distributions, including RedHat and all its branded and unbranded (CentOS/Amazon Linux/etc) derivatives.